# Sort Excel sheet by day of the week in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a sheet that has info about classes but the way the sheet is laid out is not in order of day.

It could be such as:
M, T, F, W, M, F, T

Is there a way to code this sheet to display in order like this:
M, T, W, R (R represents Thursday), F?

Comment: record a macro using the custom sort and see how excel does it?

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Wait - why doesn't the regular SORT work??

Comment: @BruceWayne regular sort would sort it F,M,R,T,W  he wants it M,T,W,R,F.  These are text representations of the day not a numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need VBA for this.

Add extra column with formula, which leads to

1 if day="M"
2 if day="T"
3 if day="W"
4 if day="R"
5 if day="F".

Then sort by that column.

Answer (score 2):

Without using VBA, you can use "Sort":

Go to Sort --> Order --> Custom List.

Then, in there, do "Add" and add "M,T,W,R,F", then Sort.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!!

Comment: @GhaithHaddad - Did this work for your project? If so, do you mind marking as the answer (click the check mark left of the post)? If not, for my knowledge, what is missing? (Perhaps need to add "S" and/or "St for Saturday/Sunday?)